# How does Cheat Engine offset calculation work?

Tags: memory, hex, address, offset, cheat-engine

I have this memory address `0F58F478` and this offset `5C`. I'm using memory sharp and it works perfectly when I'm adding this number.

```
IntPtr address = _mSharp.Read<IntPtr>(0F58F478, false) + 0x5C;
// address output: 035F4E60
```

According to Cheat Engine this would be the result `035F4E60`. But I've tried using a [Hex Calculator](https://www.calculator.net/hex-calculator.html) and the result is by far kinda different. I'd like to know how MemorySharp or CheatEngine calculates this sum.

[image]

Notice that when I add 0 to a pointer this change its value, how this works? Why 0 is adding value there?

[image]

Comment: what are you adding ?in hex calculator ?  0F58F478 + 5c  this ? >>> print(hex(0x0F58F478+0x5c)) === 0xf58f4d4 if yes then you are not dereferencing  0F58F478  is a pointer you need to read what it points to and add 0x5c to the result

Comment: Ahhhh ok, it makes sense, thanks! just one question more, why add `0x0` to the `0F58F478` pointer changes its value? (I've updated the post with a new image) Also, is a pointer the same that memory address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I Commented if you are adding 0x5c to 0x0F58F478 and getting 0xf58f4d4
it is not what the memory sharp or cheat engine does

0x0xf58f4d4  is a pointer an address in the memory space
they dereference the pointer and add 0x5c to the result

your other query why adding 0 also falls under the same category adding 0 or 10 or 5c or 100 or 987 and dereferencing them will always provide the underlying value

also keep an eye on the square brackets [] means dereference
without square brackets means direct addition
as the first entry in your screen shot shows

```
&a  = 0x0F58F478                            &a = __addressof(a);
*a  = 0x3454e04                             *a = value of a
 a  + 0x5c = 0xf58f4d4                      direct addition 
[a] + 0x5c = 0x3454e04+0x5c ==  0x3454e60   dereferenced addition
[a+ 0x5c] = [f58f4d4] = *f58f4d4 = some other value that is got by 
first adding  and then  dereferencing
```

since this appears to be c# you should try reading about unsafe / boxing / unboxing etc as it appears you are not aware of pointers,memory ,dereferencing etc

here is a boxing example in powershell

```
PS C:\> $a = 123                                                                                                        
PS C:\> $b = $a     b contains what was in $a viz 123                                                                                                    
PS C:\> $a = 456    a gets a new value and a new address                                                                                                      
PS C:\> $a,$b                                                                                                            
456
123
PS C:\>
```

or in c# unsafe construct

```
:\>dir /b
unsafe.cs

:\>type unsafe.cs
using System;
class Program
{
static unsafe void Main()
{
   int var = 32;
   int* p = &var;
   Console.WriteLine("value is 0x{0:x}" , var);
   Console.WriteLine("address is 0x{0:x}" , (int)p);
   Console.WriteLine("dereferenced is 0x{0:x}" , (*p + 0x5c));
   Console.WriteLine("undereferenced is 0x{0:x}" , ((int)p + 0x5c));
   Console.WriteLine("somegarbage  is 0x{0:x}" , *((p + 0x5c)));
}
}
:\>csc unsafe.cs /unsafe
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.10.0.0 (b9fb1610)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


:\>unsafe.exe
value is 0x20
address is 0x4feac4
dereferenced is 0x7c
undereferenced is 0x4feb20
somegarbage  is 0x0
```